# A simple clipboard manager for Gnome

Tags: clipboard, gnome

I want a **simple** clipboard manager for Gnome. (A KDE program may also be OK, but I run it in Gnome environment.) I need just to view the clipboard.

I also would like to copy fragments of the clipboard from the clipboard viewer to clipboard, without destroying what the viewer currently shows. Is it possible?

Comment: You can try GClipper, but I, personally, am unimpressed. I hope that you get a good answer to this one. I really want to find something like Ditto for Gnome.

Comment: Have you looked at [Klipper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klipper)? I use it a lot and you can even customize custom shortcuts. It can edit entries, save entries more than 100 (mine is 500), and has the feature to  save the content after exit as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command does what I need:

```
xsel -o -b | xmessage -file -
```

`xsel` retrieves the content of clipboard (`-o` passes the content to the next command in the chain of commands separated with `|`, `-b` specifies that we work with clipboards (not with PRIMARY selection for example)) and `xmessage` shows a message window to the user, with the message text received from the previous command in `|` chain.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what the commands do? Keep in mind that a future visitor might want to vet your answer and currently he would need to execute that command or start a research himself. We prefer to have answers that contain all the information necessary in the answer themselves as long as it is at all possible.

Answer (score 5):

You could try [Diodon](https://launchpad.net/diodon), a **simple** and **lightweight** clipboard manager for Gnome with application indicator support. Apparently it aims to be the best integrated clipboard manager for the Gnome/GTK+ desktop, and it's the one I know that's **still actively developed**.

News/Questions about the application can be found on the [official homepage](https://esite.ch/tag/diodon/).

I use it on Ubuntu 14.04 and it's important to say that in order for Diodon to work, [Zeitgest](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180990/what-is-zeitgeist-used-for) must be enabled (see the question "[Diodon does not save anything copied to the clipboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464850/diodon-does-not-save-anything-copied-to-the-clipboard)" on Ask Ubuntu)

This is a screenshot of the Diodon preferences:

[image: Diodon preferences]

This is the Diodon application indicator containing three elements that were just added to the clipboard:

[image: Diodon application indicator]